# Is it true that Luther intentionally mistranslated Romans 3:28?

Tags: bible-translation, martin-luther, romans, sola-fide

I recently listened to Dr. Scott Hahn's conversion testimony.  One thing that really jumped out at me was that Dr. Hahn stated that Luther purposely inserted the German word "allein" (alone) into [Romans 3:28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%203:28&version=LUTH1545) despite the fact that it is not in the Greek texts.

> So halten wir nun dafür, daß der Mensch gerecht werde ohne des Gesetzes Werke, allein durch den Glauben.

Is this true?

Are there any writings from Luther that allude to his own translation of this *crucial* verse?

Comment: Might be worth noting that the OP [did ask this on BH](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/is-it-true-that-luther-intentionally-mistranslated-romans-328) later on: